# Find Universe meta Data Information in BO SDK R4

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am new to BO, I need to find universe name and the corresponding metadata information like(Table name, column names, join conditions etc...). I am unable to find proper way to start. I looked with Data Access SDK, Semantic SDk. 
Can any one please provide me the sample code or procedure for starting..
I googled a lot but i am unable to find any sample examples 
I looked into this link  but that code will  work only on R2 Server.

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=67088

Help is Highly Apprecitated.....

Comment: Are you looking for this information by report or you know the universe and just need a list of this information?

Comment: I want to know Universal releated metadata like What tables used, joins, conditions etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about IDT based universes, you'll need to code some Java. [The JavaDoc for the API is available here](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/bip/40/slsdk/en/index.html).

In a nutshell, you do something like this:

```
SlContext context = SlContext.create() ;
LocalResourceService service = context.getService(LocalResourceService.class) ;
String blxFile = service.retrieve("universe.unx","output directory") ;
RelationalBusinessLayer businessLayer = (RelationalBusinessLayer)service.load(blxFile);
RootFolder rootFolder  = businessLayer.getRootFolder() ;
```

Once you have a hook on the rootFolder, you can use the getChildren() method to drill into the folder structure and access the various subfolders/business objects available.

You may also want to check the CmsResourceService class to access universes stored on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

To get the information you are after will require a 2 part solution.  Part 1 use the Rebean SDK looking at WebI reports for the Universe and object names being used with in it.

Part 2 is to break out your favorite COM programming tool, *since I try to avoid COM I use the Excel Macro editor*, and access the BusinessObjects Designer library.  Main code snippets that I currently have are:

```
Dim boUniv As Designer.Universe
Dim tbl As Designer.Table
For Each tbl In boUniv.Tables
  Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next tbl
```

This prints all of the tables in a universe.

You will need to combine the 2 parts on your own for a dependency list between WebI reports and Universes.